# Have the GPIO pins changed between the Pi 2 and the Pi 3?

Tags: gpio, pi-3, pi-2, debug

I am trying to get jtag debugging to work and I was wondering whether the pins between the Pi 2 and Pi 3 have any important differences. Because the jtag seggers device I have is connected to a soldered board designed specifically for the Pi 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For reference here is a diagram of the GPIO for the Pi 2 and the Pi 3:

[image]

The GPIO layout is the same, differences between the Pi 2 and Pi 3 include:

- The Pi 3 has on-board Wi-Fi and Bluetooth
- The Raspberry Pi 2 has a quad-core 900MHz CPU, the Pi 3 a quad-core 1.2GHz one. Both have 1GB RAM and both use a fourth-generation VideoCore CPU
- The Pi 2 uses a Cortex-A7 set , whereas the Pi 3 uses a Cortex-A53 with 64 bit architecture
- The Pi 2's GPU is clocked at 250 MHz, whilst the Pi 3's runs at 400MHz
- The Memory on the Pi 2 runs at 450MHz, whereas the Pi 3's runs at 900MHz

I believe the power requirements for both are the same. So a power supply that worked with the Pi 2 should work just fine with the Pi 3.

The layout of both boards is exceptionally similar so any cases or enclosures you had for the Pi 2 would probably work with the Pi 3.